# Getting an iPhone app's product name at runtime?

Tags: ios, iphone

How can this be achieved? I would like to get the name so i can display it within an app, without having to change it in code each time i change a name, of course.

Answer (score 143):

Try this

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSDictionary *info = [bundle infoDictionary];
NSString *prodName = [info objectForKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"];
```

Comment: CFBundleDisplayName returns the Bundle Display Name.  OP asked for the Product Name.  For this use CFBundleName.  In most cases the two will be the same, but may be different if you set a new display name (for something displayed under the icon which is not suitable as a filename).

Comment: Apple discusses this in a [technical article.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1544/_index.html). Of particular note is that there's no constant for `CFBundleDisplayName` -- a string literal is the right thing to use.

Comment: @ChrisNewman is incorrect: CFBundleName is absolutely NOT the Product Name (you can check this by changing one but not the other in your xcode settings). They default to being the same. (I discovered this the hard way).

Comment: Since my comment was made obsolete somewhere between 1 and 3 SDK versions ago, what is the current correct answer to this question?

Answer (score 57):

Good answers here. I would add one thing though.

Rather than using @"CFBundleDisplayName", which has the potential to change in future, it's best to cast the string constant supplied in CFBundle.h like so:

```
[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:(NSString*)kCFBundleNameKey];
```

Thus future-proofing your code.

Comment: This is a different key and might not be the display name in all cases. Surprisingly, a string literal is what [Apple recommends](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1544/_index.html) for this particular case.

Answer (score 45):

According to Apple, using `- objectForInfoDictionaryKey:` directly on the `NSBundle` object is preferred:

> Use of this method is preferred over other access methods because it returns the localized value of a key when one is available.

Here's an example in Swift:

```
let appName = NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey("CFBundleName") as! String
// Or use key "CFBundleDisplayName"
```

Update for Swift 3 - thanks Jef.

```
let appName = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleName") as! String
```

Comment: Come on people... this is the quality answer.

Comment: has changed significantly for swift3 -    let appName = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleName") as! String

Comment: Could use the constant `kCFBundleNameKey` instead of a simple string: `kCFBundleNameKey as String`

Answer (score 14):

I had a problem when I localize my application name by using InfoPlist.strings, like

```
CFBundleDisplayName = "My Localized App Name";
```

I could not obtain localized application name if I use infoDictionary.

In that case I used localizedInfoDirectory like below.

```
NSDictionary *locinfo = [bundle localizedInfoDictionary];
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use the direct approach,

```
NSString* appName = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"];
```

Answer (score 6):

For completeness, Swift 3.0 would be;

```
let appName = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleDisplayName") as! String
```

Comment: Why vote down with no comment? The code works and the answer isn't a duplicate :/

Comment: This is actually not answering the question which is asking for the Product Name which can be set differently than the Bundle Display Name.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the cleanest approach I could come up with using Swift 3:

```
let productName = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleDisplayName"] as? String
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Xamarin.iOS version of @epatel's answer:

```
var prodName = NSBundle.MainBundle.InfoDictionary.ObjectForKey(new NSString("CFBundleDisplayName")) as NSString;
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is as follows. Be aware that this returns the name of your app's bundle, which you can change to be different from your app's product name.

```
// (Swift 5)
static let bundleName = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: kCFBundleNameKey as String) as! String
```

If you need your app to have a different name from the bundle and may change Info.plist, you could do something like the following:

```
// (Swift 5)
// To use this, include a key and value in your app's Info.plist file:
// Key: ProductName
// Value: $(PRODUCT_NAME)
// By default PRODUCT_NAME is the same as your project build target name, $(TARGET_NAME), but this may be changed.
// If you do so, you may wish to change the CFBundleName value to $(TARGET_NAME) in the Info.plist file.
// PRODUCT_NAME is defined in the target's Build Settings in the Packaging section.
static let productName = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "ProductName") as! String
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a swift update for this very old question. I was in need of swift answer and it was kind of tricky(Unwrapping optionals) in swift syntax so sharing it here

```
let productName = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary!["CFBundleName"]!
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code would be better.

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSDictionary *info = [bundle infoDictionary];
self.appName = [info objectForKey:@"CFBundleExecutable"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let productName =  Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleName"] as? String
```

[image]

```
let displayName =  Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleDisplayName"] as? String
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

You could have all bundle details from this dictionary "info". print this dictionary and get what you want.

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSDictionary *info = [bundle infoDictionary];
```