# How to set FacebookUrlSchemeSuffix build hint in Codename One

Tags: ios, facebook, codenameone

I have two free and paid apps which use same one Facebook app.

- The free app has package: com.company.app
- The paid app has package: com.company.app.free

The facebook app has id is *123456* and the iOS platform section in Facebook app:

- "*Bundle ID*": com.company.app.free, com.company.app
- "*URL Scheme Suffix*": free, paid

I *can't logon* the facebook in freeApp because the facebook *always* *redirects* to the paidApp.

After spend time, I found the [Two iOS apps using the same Facebook app ID - is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993996/two-ios-apps-using-the-same-facebook-app-id-is-it-possible) and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/troubleshooting#sharedappid and try:

- Add the ios.FacebookUrlSchemeSuffix="free" for freeApp and ios.FacebookUrlSchemeSuffix="paid" for paidApp but the problem is still same.
- Then remove the ios.FacebookUrlSchemeSuffix build hint above, add the ios.plistInject=< key>FacebookUrlSchemeSuffix< /key>< string>free < /string> for freeApp and test it. The app is terminated immediately when start logon the facebook.
- Then add the ios.urlScheme=fb123456 to the freeApp but the build is failed at server with error "*...Info.plist': The data couldnâ€™t be read because it isnâ€™t in the correct format.*"

What are correct setting for *ios.urlScheme* and *ios.plistInject* build hints (include the *FacebookUrlSchemeSuffix*) in order for both freeApp and paidApp can work correctly in Codename One?

Answer (score 0):

> ios.urlScheme
>
> Allows intercepting a URL call using the syntax
>   urlPrefix

From: https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html

Notice that by default defining Facebook support includes the main URL scheme so the plistInject will conflict with that.

Comment: Shai, do you have any advice in order to make both my free and paid apps can work?

Comment: I have no experience with that so I don't know specifically my answer is about the URL scheme portion of the question.

Comment: My both free and paid apps can work correctly by setting the ios.urlScheme=<string>free</string> and ios.urlScheme=<string>paid</string>

Comment: So does that work or do I need to look further into this? Looking a bit into it I don't see why you would need this. If you set the facebook appid to be the same for both apps it should "just work".

Comment: Apps currently work now. Don't need to look into it. Thanks. when I set FacebookUrlSchemeSuffix=free and ios.urlScheme=<string>free</string> the plist file is generated <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
-<array>
<string>fb534305660081488</string>
<string>fb534305660081488free</string>
</array>  and it works.