# Facebook's login opens the wrong app

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I'm trying to implement the login of an app with facebook but every time I try to login, it suggests opening the wrong app.

I've tried some things I found over here but it didn't work.

On facebook's developers page I've added a suffix:

[image: developers page]

And my .plist is the following:

[image]

Does anyone knows what's going on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, Were you able to solve the problem? I have a similar problem. In my case, another app has "Login with Facebook app" feature and when the user taps on it, it suggests the user to open in my app. Do you know on which side the problem is?

Comment: Not yet @KaranveerSingh. That was exactly my problem.

Comment: I found the problem. The problem was on my side which means that in your case, the problem is on the other app's side.

Comment: Hello @KaranveerSingh, I'm facing the same problem you encountered. Could you tell me what problem you had on your side and how you fixed it?

Comment: @DoncaBogdan Make sure you have added the following in your .plist. <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>fbapi</string>
  <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
  <string>fbauth2</string>
  <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>

Comment: @DoncaBogdan That was the problem on my side. I had not added the above code. Also, do enable "Single Sign On".

Comment: @KaranveerSingh, thanks a lot for the quick response!

Comment: for more detailed explaination refer to this link:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993996/two-ios-apps-using-the-same-facebook-app-id-is-it-possible)

Answer (score 1):

Just as workaround you can remove fb ids like

```
<string>fbauth2</string>
```

under

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
```

from `Info.plist`

This leads to the fact that the application will try to authorize via safari, not via Facebook App.

Comment: removing fbauth2 crashes the application.