# Facebook Login on iOS opens the wrong app

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-login

An user is trying to login with Facebook in my app. He has an iPhone 4S, iOS 9, and has the Facebook App installed.

When trying to login he receives an alert asking for "Open in ". If he accepts the suggestion, the other app is opened and he can't login into my app. If he cancels he doesn't login as well.

In his specific case the unrelated app was "Sweatt", and when he uninstalled it he was able to login with the Facebook app. Though, upon logging in, in my app the button "Return to Facebook" appeared on the top left corner, as if my app was executed by Facebook and not the other way around.

Any tips? Might this be an issue specific to iOS 9?

Comment: Is there a URL scheme clash? Do the 2 apps define the same URL scheme for being opened?

Comment: Have you checked your application to ensure you've not transposed any of the Facebook credentials? If everything is right, this could be an occurrence of Collision and you should submit feedback to Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

Check is `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` is correct in your app.

Also for such situation check this workaround solution:

[Facebook's login opens the wrong app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44619871/facebooks-login-opens-the-wrong-app/53415342#53415342)